# Last column in a table is too wide

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have been trying to create a table detailing the changes in speed over time, and have noticed that the last column (22 seconds) is disproportionately wide. Is there any way I can reduce the size of it so that it is the same width as the others?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|X|}
\hline
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
 \hline
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}\\
```

Comment: you don't need tabularx try \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
 \hline
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: also don't use `\\ ` after `\end{center}`

Answer (score 5):

If you want the table to span a certain width, e.g., the width of the text block, but don't need (or want) all columns to be equally wide, you could employ a `tabular*` environment instead of the `tabularx` environment you're using at the moment. (The directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` serves to insert additional intercolumn whitespace.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l| *{12}{l|} }
\hline
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
 \hline
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Echoing the comments made by @BenediktBauer in his answer, you may want to give some serious thought to omitting all vertical bars -- trust me, they add clutter rather than provide clarity -- and to replacing the `\hline` directives with the macros of the `booktabs` package, as they produce horizontal lines with much improved spacing properties.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt} % let tabular* figure out the intercolumn separation
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ @{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{r} @{}}
\toprule
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
\midrule
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have you removed the side padding?

Comment: I'm in reasonably good company in this regard: Simon Fear, the creator of the `booktabs` package, also inserts `@{}` to left of the first column and to the right of the final column. More generally, I don't see the need to provide padding in these two places unless the table features vertical bars in these two locations -- which, of course, shouldn't be necessary in a well-designed table.

Comment: ah ok. Something I don't do (and probably won't start doing, but I might see). It as well explains why `\cmidrule` has so "bad" UI :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `X` column type of the `tabularx` environment. A `tabularx` basically stretches a table to the width it has been given as parameter (`\columnwidth` in your case). In this context the `X` column takes over all the space that is not occupied by the other columns to expand the table to the full width. If you have several `X` columns, the available space will be equally distributed among them.

To solve your problem, you can either set all but the first column to be an `X` column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
\hline
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Or, if the table does not necessarily be full column width, just use the normal `tabular` environment with all `l` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Time (sec)    & 0  & 2  & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 \\
\hline
Speed (m/sec) & 10 & 14 & 20 & 24 & 22 & 18 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 11 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For tables containing numbers I would prefer the latter solution.

Also, just as a comment concerning style: from a typographic point of view vertical lines in tables are concerned bad as they disturb readability of the table and should only be used very sparsely to highlight/clarify certain features of the table. Try to not stick too much to this Excel-like style of table formatting!